# Controlling Daemon Software via Shell Script with Cron

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu

I recently installed "The Fat Controller" software (http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/) on my server (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) to daemonise a PHP script I need to run constantly.

It works perfectly, but at this moment I have to control it from the shell manually with the following commands.

Starting

> /etc/init.d/fatcontrollerd start

Stopping

> /etc/init.d/fatcontrollerd stop

Is it running?

> /etc/init.d/fatcontrollerd status

Basically, I want to setup a shell script that I call with cron that would do the same process I would do manually, automatically every minute (Check if it's running --> If it is, do nothing --> If it is not, start it).

When I type the "Is it running" while it is running command in the shell, I get the response "Running". How can I write a shell script to send this "Is it running" command and run the "start" command if, "Is it running" does not respond with "Running"?

I am very inexperienced in the shell, but did get a previous daemon script to work (that failed horribly). So I know how to get it hooked into cron, I just can't find the syntax on how to run these commands automatically, make a decision and then run another command if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your script in php too, and for running an external process and get the output you can use the [shell-exec](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) function, so you can use something like:

```
$output = shell_exec("/etc/init.d/fatcontrollerd status");
if ($output == "Running") {
    // do what you need to do!!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will give this a shot and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: I get the output "You need root privileges to run this script". How can I give PHP the rights to run this command?

Comment: Got it working:

`$output = trim(shell_exec("sudo /bin/daemonizer.sh status"));
if($output == "Running")
{
 $logTxt = "POLL DAEMON RUNNING - DO NOTHING";
}
else
{
 $startOutput = shell_exec("sudo /bin/daemonizer.sh start");
 $logTxt = "POLL DAEMON NOT RUNNING - TRY TO RESTART!";
}`